# how to protect access to my apps and/or data automatically?

Tags: applications, security, auto-start, privacy

I want to lock access to my apps and I installed an app (Applock), which works properly only after being manually opened.

I need some solution which lets me being protected from having my data shared without needing to open the mentioned app itself; I'm focusing on the case when you have your phone stolen and anyone may have access to the screen, and I don't want to configure the screen locker.
The App I've installed seems to be configured for being launched at system startup but I still have to manually open it to have my apps locked.

Is there any app or method which may prevent others to use my apps and which is automatically operative at system startup?

Comment: What do you want/need that the lock screen does not provide?

Comment: @mattm if someone steals my phone I want to let him have access to browsers and settings so I can track his activities, but I don't want to share my personal data at the same time. The best solution would be a guest account but my phone doesn't allow to configure it.